# Atom portable location

Tags: atom-editor

When we run:

```
C:\> atom --portable
```

the relavent contents from `~/.atom` are copied to a new home directory in the `Portable Mode location`. But where is the `Portable Mode location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment variable `ATOM_HOME` is where the relevant contents will be copied. Also you need the `.atom/` and `Atom` to be sibling folders. So if you're using dropbox for your portable atom you would need

```
dropbox/.atom
dropbox/Atom/atom.exe
```